# Extracting GEE time series in one step

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

I want to extract values across an imageCollection for a specific location. I can do that (using an R and the package rgee, but I think that same could be done in python etc.) looping through the images or using lapply. However, is there a way to reduce the entire imageCollection to the specific location and extract everything at once?

```
#### Initialise GEE 
library(rgee)  
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv("gee-demo", conda = "auto",required = TRUE)

ee = import("ee")
ee$Initialize()

np = import("numpy")
pd = import("pandas")


roi <- ee$Geometry$Point(c(123.813785, 72.629130))

## MODIS collection
Mod09  = ee$ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09GA")$
  filterDate(ee$Date('2016-05-01'), ee$Date('2016-05-31'))$
  filterBounds(roi)
dts <- as.POSIXct(sapply(Mod09$getInfo()[[6]], function(x) x$properties$`system:index`), format = "%Y_%m_%d")

outB1 <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(dts), function(x) {
  im  <- ee$Image(Mod09$toList(length(dts))$get(x-1))
  red <- im$reduceRegion(ee$Reducer$first(), roi, 1)
  red$select(list("sur_refl_b01"))$getInfo()
}))
```

I tried to reduce the imageCollection by mapping:

```
redColl = Mod09$map(function(image) {
  return(image$reduceRegion(ee$Reducer$first()$setOutputs(image$bandNames()), roi, 1))$
    map(function(feature) {
      return(feature.set({
        'imageID' = image$id()
        'B1'= image$get('sur_refl_b01')
      }))
    }) 
})$flatten()
```

But so far this does not work.